# Pandas Dataframe Transformation, looking for elegant solution

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe called `t1`. I need to get from `t1` the data for the year 2008 so I tried this:

```py
t08= t1[t1['time'].str.startswith('2008')]
t08.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
t08 = t08[['time','temperature']]
```

After that I need `t08` to be a Dataframe. According to warnings it is not the case at this moment. A very inelegant way that worked for me was:

```py
t08.to_csv(r'C:\...\generic\zw4.csv')
t2_08 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\...\generic\zw4.csv')
```

So now pandas is recognizing `t2_08` as a dataframe. But what would be a more elegant way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share a sample of your t1 dataframe , basically the available columns etc to assist

Comment: I assume a simple `pd.DataFrame(t08)` doesn't work then?

Comment: 1. yes of course... you will find t1 here called 'ninjatemp.csv'
https://github.com/JulianLeGrid/Bach

2. pd.DataFrame(t08) does not work

Comment: If it is not a dataframe, have you checked what type of object it is? Before you strip out the two columns 'time' and 'temperature' is it a dataframe? Have you tried instead of using inplace=True, just assigning the new dataframe to t08?

Comment: I followed your first code exert exactly and used the dataframe you linked to. I had no errors and the result was a dataframe.

Comment: What warnings? [t08 is a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68750153/383793)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you can do `t08.to_csv` is a give away that it is probably a `DataFrame`:

```
t1 = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/JulianLeGrid/Bach/blob/main/ninjatemp.csv?raw=true')
t08 = t1[t1['time'].str.startswith('2008')]
t08.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
t08 = t08[['time','temperature']]
assert isinstance(t08, pd.DataFrame)
```